# What are the size limits of contract storage in ink?

Tags: ink, storage

Whilst reading the [docs](https://use.ink/datastructures/storage-layout) for ink I came across this warning:

> CAUTION
> If any type exhibiting Packed layout gets large enough (an ever-growing Vec might be a prime candidate for this), it will break your contract. This is because for encoding and decoding storage items, there is a buffer with only limited capacity (around 16KB in the default configuration) available. This means any contract trying to decode more than that will trap! If you are unsure about the potential size a data structure might get, consider using an ink! Mapping, which can store an arbitrary number of elements, instead.

It looks like the `StorageLayout` has been changed from this [pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1331), so I'm not sure if this is still an issue. However, it has made me wonder about the size constraints of the variables I am using in my contract storage.

So for my contract storage in `ink`, given:

1. `Mapping<A,B>`, how large can `A` be?
2. `Mapping<A,B>`, how large can `B` be?
3. `Mapping<A,B>`, what's the max number of key-value pairs the map can handle?
4. `Vec<A>`, what's the max length of the vec?
5. `Vec<A>`, what's the max size of `A`?
6. `Lazy<Vec<A>>`, does the lazy container change any size limits of (4) or (5)?
7. Is there an overall contract storage size limit?
8. Will these limits change per chain? The warning above mentioned "16KB in the default configuration" so I assume this varies?